# Test authoring with CMocka

Tags: c, unit-testing, cmocka

a little background: I wish to unit test my code which gets built into a shared object file, say `libabc`. This code also calls `libjson-c` and `libcurl` functions.

I am planning to write function-wise tests for each function in product code, mocking calls to other functions from `libabc`, `libjson-c` and `libcurl`. Now I can't arrange all tests for a given file `a.c` in a single test file as in each test I would be required to mock different functions from `a.c`.

Also, in a single test, I would want to mock all function calls to `libjson-c` and `libcurl` so that I won't have to link (`gcc -lcurl -ljson-c`) the dependencies and this requires writing `__wrap` functions for all the functions called from `a.c`. But since each test case would want some particular code to be present in the wrapped functions, I can't just wrap them once and for all.

Any ideas around how are the tests with CMocka authored and arranged? Should I create a separate test file that gets compiled in an executable for tests of a product code function?

Answer (score -3):

I am not familiar with Cmocka but I really like ceedling with cmocks and use it every day.